# Wordpress - CSS Doesn't Put Image Inside Circle

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using the Featured Post with Thumbnail plugin and I have edited the plugin's CSS file (featured-post.css) to make the images show up inside a circle. Here is the code i have:

```
ul#yiw-featured-post .featured-thumb {float:left;margin-right:1em;
background-color: #F5F5F5;      
border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;      
border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;      
padding: 4px; 
}
```

When i preview the page I can see the circle but it is behind the image. The images are just layed overtop of the circle. I was hoping the images would be cropped down to fill the circle like the Jetpack Circle Tiled Gallery examples. I'm not sure what to add to the code to make the images adjust correctly.

adding:
It's a plugin so i use the widget to display the recent posts, so there is no set HTML because the image links would change depending on the article that's shown. But here is what it looks like right now:

```
<div id="widget_featured-posts-3" class="widget"><h5>Featured Posts</h5>    
<ul id="yiw-featured-post">
   <li class="first-child">
       <a href="http://herdailyfix.com/2013/10/its-the-relaunch/" class="featured-thumb">
                      <img src="http://herdailyfix.com/wp-content/plugins/featured-post-with-thumbnail/scripts/timthumb.php?src=http://herdailyfix.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/hdf_bannerMay1.png&amp;h=300&amp;w=300&amp;zc=1" class="alignleft" alt="It’s The Relaunch!…">

               </a>

       <h4 class="featured-title">
           <a href="http://herdailyfix.com/2013/10/its-the-relaunch/">It’s The Relaunch!…</a>
       </h4>
   </li>
   <li>
       <a href="http://herdailyfix.com/2011/07/monday-feature-do-you-fall-too-hard-too-soon/" class="featured-thumb">
                      <img src="http://herdailyfix.com/wp-content/plugins/featured-post-with-thumbnail/scripts/timthumb.php?src=http://herdailyfix.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/black-couple.jpg&amp;h=300&amp;w=300&amp;zc=1" class="alignleft" alt="monday feature: Do You Fall Too Hard, Too Soon?">

               </a>

       <h4 class="featured-title">
           <a href="http://herdailyfix.com/2011/07/monday-feature-do-you-fall-too-hard-too-soon/">monday feature: Do You Fall Too Hard, Too Soon?</a>
       </h4>
   </li>
   <li class="last-child">
       <a href="http://herdailyfix.com/2013/11/the-best-man-holiday/" class="featured-thumb">
                      <img src="http://herdailyfix.com/wp-content/plugins/featured-post-with-thumbnail/scripts/timthumb.php?src=http://herdailyfix.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/bestman.jpg&amp;h=300&amp;w=300&amp;zc=1" class="alignleft" alt="The Best Man Holiday: No Spoilers!">

               </a>

       <h4 class="featured-title">
           <a href="http://herdailyfix.com/2013/11/the-best-man-holiday/">The Best Man Holiday: No Spoilers!</a>
       </h4>
   </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Can't help unless you provide the relevant bits of html.

Comment: @cale_b i added the code that's generated by the plugin once it's on the website. does that help any?

Comment: Indeed it does - you've got an answer, and it looks good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `oveflow: hidden;` to `ul#yiw-featured-post .featured-thumb` and add this for image inside anchor tag:

```
ul#yiw-featured-post .featured-thumb img {
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
    display: block;
}
```

So the full code will be:

```
ul#yiw-featured-post .featured-thumb {
    float:left;
    margin-right:1em;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
    padding: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul#yiw-featured-post .featured-thumb img {
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
    display: block;
}
```

Here is demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6fAP5/